# Properties, Types and Python

Tags: python

Using Properties, I figured one can easily get things mixed up. Like the code below, I'd love `id` to be of type `int` but don't know if Python can allow me do that without a try statement and catching ValueError

```
def getter(self):
    return id

def setter(self, id):
    self.id = id
```

If I input `'boy'` instead of `1` in there, the code still run. Is there a way to eliminate this?

Comment: [This behaviour is by design.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can just call int on id:

```
def setter(self, id):
  self.id = int(id)
```

now passing `1` or `"1"` will work, but passing `"boy"` will raise an exception

Comment: Mmm... Isn't "1" a type str? I was hoping I could get a c# solution. Thank you, by the way.

Comment: @Gusto_ yes "1" is a str, but doing int("1") will return a type int, so self.id will always be an int

Answer (score 1):

```
def setter(self, id):
    if not isinstance(id, int):
        raise TypeError("dude, id has to be int")
    self.id = id
```

Now if someone passes incorrect input you should wrap the assignment code with `try:except:` block and handle it as you wish.

Comment: Prefer Arsh's answer as it asks "can you act like an int" as opposed to "are you an int" - duck typing is more pythonic.

Comment: @CaptainMurphy Every solution has strong and weak sides. With my solution he could raise a custom exception and catch it somewhere else (and don't worry that he'll catch something he doesn't want to or he wants to catch somewhere else). Also "pythonic" is a word havily overused nowadays. Everything is pythonic as long as it solves the problem.

Comment: I really do not want to do a if/try-catch statement. I guess that is a "limitation" right there.

Comment: @freakish Respectfully disagree about pythonic - perhaps the word is overused but the concept is underused. I use it to mean "not blindly using constructs from other languages when better facilities are available in python".